# Get view count using Google Youtube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, google-api-java-client

I want to get the view count of set of videos. Following is the relevant part of my code.

```
  SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
  ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();

  // Double checks the kind is video.
  if (rId.getKind().equals("youtube#video")) {
    Thumbnail thumbnail = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().get("default");

    System.out.println(" Video Id" + rId.getVideoId());
    System.out.println(" Title: " + singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
    System.out.println(" Thumbnail: " + thumbnail.getUrl());

    YouTube.Videos.List list = youtube.videos().list("statistics");
    list.setId(rId.getVideoId());
    list.setKey("youtube.apikey");            
    Video v = list.execute().getItems().get(0);
    System.out.println("The view count is: "+v.getStatistics().getViewCount());
    System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
  }
```

This gives the following error in the line "YouTube.Videos.Lists list = youtube.videos().list("statistics");".

```
error: method list in class YouTube.Videos cannot be applied to given types;
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a compilation error then there might be some issue with the library version that you have included. I tried sample code from [youtube API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#examples) and it worked for me.

I have removed some extra code from the sample to show how view counts can be retrieved for a single video:

```
    import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
    import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
    import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
    import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;
    import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
    import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;
    import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoListResponse;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.math.BigInteger;

public class GeolocationSearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
            }).setApplicationName("APP_ID").build();

            String apiKey = "API_KEY";
            YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("statistics");
            listVideosRequest.setId("lf_wVfwpfp8"); // add list of video IDs here
            listVideosRequest.setKey(apiKey);
            VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();

            Video video = listResponse.getItems().get(0);

            BigInteger viewCount = video.getStatistics().getViewCount();

            System.out.println(" ViewCount: " + viewCount);
            System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");

        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```