# Youtube Video Statistical Information in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, youtube, statistics

I would like to retrieve the statistical information for a youtube video in MATLAB e.g., Views with time, Likes, Dislikes e.t.c. Can anybody let me know how can i do this? OR if there is any API available for getting youtube videos statistical information, how can i retrieve this information in MATLAB?

Comment: unfortunately, your question is out of context, you are better off tagging it with API instead of Matlab, since you will be retrieving/scrapping the data into text/csv files first before you can load it into Matlab.

Comment: Check this link (https://developers.google.com/youtube/code_samples). There are several other languages you can do it. I asked the same question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564057/get-view-count-using-google-youtube-api). May be the answer will help you.

Comment: If google gives u some C/C++/Java/C# API's to pull such statistics, you can write your code in those languages and call them from MATLAB using MEX (C/C++) or directly if you are using Java or C#

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no.  Don't use Matlab for this.  Use R, or even Python, if you don't know R.

Please see these links for some ideas of how to get started.
http://zevross.com/blog/2015/05/19/scrape-website-data-with-the-new-r-package-rvest/

http://giventhedata.blogspot.com/2012/08/r-and-web-for-beginners-part-iii.html

Comment: This is at best a link only answer but is more realistically simply not an answer.