# get youtube video basic info in java youtube api v3?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-data-api

To be precise I want to get a youtube video Basic info such as: Views, Likes, Dislikes.

I found this question about: [Get view count using Google Youtube API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564057/get-view-count-using-google-youtube-api)

But I am getting the error at `Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT and Auth.JSON_FACTORY` class doesn't exist error.

By your request my code:

```
 import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
 import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
 import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
 import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
 import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;
 import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoListResponse;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.math.BigInteger;

public class DBConnect {
    public String getyoutubeitemfull_details(String URI) throws SQLException, IOException{
        try {
            YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
        }).setApplicationName("APP_ID").build();

            String apiKey = "API_KEY";
            YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("statistics");
            listVideosRequest.setId("lf_wVfwpfp8"); // add list of video IDs here
            listVideosRequest.setKey(apiKey);
            VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();

            Video video = listResponse.getItems().get(0);    

            BigInteger viewCount = video.getStatistics().getViewCount();

            System.out.println(" ViewCount: " + viewCount);
              System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");

        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Youtube");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: how about you show your code?

Comment: @Stultuske see my Question update

Comment: do you have the Auth class on your classpath?

Comment: @Stultuske ahh no i don't have it

Comment: @Stultuske hey can u give me a link for app youtube API libs to download i suppose I am missing the `com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth;` from my class path

Comment: check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876297/what-is-jar-file-contains-com-google-api-services-samples-youtube-cmdline-auth-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Future generation.

In order to get basic info of a youtube video based on its ID This would work:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.Video;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.VideoListResponse;

import duck.reg.pack.Auth;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class DBConnect {

    public String getyoutubeitemfull_details() throws SQLException, IOException{
        try {
            YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
                }
            }).setApplicationName("APP_ID").build();

            String apiKey = "Your Private Api Key"; // you can get it from https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
            YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("statistics");
            listVideosRequest.setId("yVcMc9HVXvc"); // add list of video IDs here
            listVideosRequest.setKey(apiKey);
            VideoListResponse listResponse = listVideosRequest.execute();

            Video video = listResponse.getItems().get(0);

            BigInteger viewCount = video.getStatistics().getViewCount();
            BigInteger Likes = video.getStatistics().getLikeCount();
            BigInteger DisLikes = video.getStatistics().getDislikeCount();
            BigInteger Comments = video.getStatistics().getCommentCount();
            System.out.println("[View Count] " + viewCount);
            System.out.println("[Likes] " + Likes);
            System.out.println("[Dislikes] " + DisLikes);
            System.out.println("[Comments] " + Comments);

        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Note:** `duck.reg.pack.Auth` is required for the API to work, but normally `Auth` class doesn't come with the youtube API libs. So what you can do is to create a new class calling it `Auth` and Copy/Paste bellow code:

**Auth.java:**

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.StoredCredential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStore;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Shared class used by every sample. Contains methods for authorizing a user and caching credentials.
 */
public class Auth {

    /**
     * Define a global instance of the HTTP transport.
     */
    public static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();

    /**
     * Define a global instance of the JSON factory.
     */
    public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

    /**
     * This is the directory that will be used under the user's home directory where OAuth tokens will be stored.
     */
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY = ".oauth-credentials";

    /**
     * Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data.
     *
     * @param scopes              list of scopes needed to run youtube upload.
     * @param credentialDatastore name of the credential datastore to cache OAuth tokens
     */
    public static Credential authorize(List<String> scopes, String credentialDatastore) throws IOException {

        // Load client secrets.
        Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader);

        // Checks that the defaults have been replaced (Default = "Enter X here").
        if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
            || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
            System.out.println(
                "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential "
                        + "into src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // This creates the credentials datastore at ~/.oauth-credentials/${credentialDatastore}
        FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY));
        DataStore<StoredCredential> datastore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(credentialDatastore);

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes).setCredentialDataStore(datastore)
            .build();

        // Build the local server and bind it to port 8080
        LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();

        // Authorize.
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
    }
}
```

Then just call `getyoutubeitemfull_details` as:

```
DBConnect youtube_binfo = new DBConnect();
youtube_info.getyoutubeitemfull_details();
```

Thanks to @Stultuske with helping me finding my solution.